# Htaccess rewrite rule weird match

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have the following rewrite rule:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index\.php/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I want to redirect all urls of type:

```
http://www.domain.com/index.php/any-character-here
```

to

```
http://www.domain.com/any-character-here
```

My problem is that it also matches URLs like:

```
http://www.domain.com/index/any-character-here
```

I've commented out all the other rules to make sure this is the one matching and it does.
Any idea why is matching the second type of URL?

Thanks

Comment: `index.php` cannot match `index`. Can you show your full .htaccess?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking as well but I'm seeing it doing the redirect. Unfortunately I can't post the full .htaccess, but like I said I've commented out all the other rules, leaving just the one above. I can also confirm that there is no folder called /index/

Comment: Difficult to guess without all the facts. Enable `RewriteLog` and see what it spits out.

Comment: I've enabled RewriteLog and there is something that is doing "add path info postfix" and "rewrites" it to index.php, so I'm researching now to see what can cause that. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have `MultiViews` option (content negotiation) turned on. Disable it by using this line on top:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

- Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs before `mod_rewrite` and and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out, your comment about `RewriteLog` was the hint.